# Histogram on R Studio

Tags: programming

I am new to R and I am trying to plot a histogram from one of the columns in my csv file. The table is already being read perfectly as I can check on R Studios date view. I also can plot histograms of vectors i create using a simples control like:

X <- 1:100
hist(x)

However, when i try to plot from my table, it says: 
Error in hist(b) : object 'b' not found

My table as a header, and i can check it using the command:
names(data)

Why can't i seem to plot the histogram from my read data?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about quantitative finance. While you might want to plot financial data, this is a general R question that is probably better suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your global environment if the data is a numeric or integer. You may get an error if it is reading in as a character string, etc.

Also you should be referencing the column name in your code assuming you have multiple columns being pulled in. Like this hist(foo$bar).

Suggest you look at ggplot's histograms [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html).

Comment: I explicitly recommend ggplot2. It takes a while to learn the syntax but its worth it.